# From what range can you see a Raid Battle?

Tags: pokemon-go

I live in a rural area, and I am lucky enough that I can see 1 Gym around me from my house. Their are just beyond the horizon 2 more Gyms. If there is a Raid battle starting over there (in the 2 far away Gyms), will it also show in my Pokemon Go app, 'Raids' tab?

Does anyone know for example the distance that you get a notification for what a Raid Battle is about to start?

Comment: I believe the distance is the same mechanism as used for the Nearby pokemon.  Consider that gyms now combine pokestops.  Plus, you may click on a raid gym to see the location animation, the same mechanism as for locating a pokemon at a pokestop.

Comment: That would make sence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can see the Gym, you can see if there's a Raid Battle going on. If you can't see the Gym, you also won't see the Raid Battle.

"A Raid Battle is About to start nearby" refers to the Gyms which you can see. (just like above)